# Can grep output the result in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, grep, posix

Is it possible to encode the output of a grep command in UTF-8 no matter what the encoding of the input file was?

I execute a grep statement in a python script (subprocess) and I want to guarantee the resulting bytes are UTF-8.

Example:

```
grep -P "ÄA" -m -1 file.txt
```

I dont know the input encoding of the file...

Comment: No, that's not grep's job. There's a different tool for recoding: `iconv`.

Comment: Besides, it is never possible to recode something "no matter what the encoding of the input file was". You can only recode something with a known encoding, you explicitly pick one. You can use a tool to *guess* at encodings, but guessing can be wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thx: for the clarfications, I thought about that, but wasnt sure :-)

Answer (score 3):

Grep follows [the UNIX philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well), that is, it does *one thing*, and it does this one thing well. File encoding is not part of that one thing.

That's what other tools are for. There is another tool that does *character decoding and encoding well*, called [`iconv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv). Use that to change the encoding of the input file to UTF-8.

This does require you to *know* the input file encoding. If you don't know,  you have to guess, based on heuristic analysis of the input file (it'll be hard to be *certain*, recognising that something has been decoded using the wrong codec usually requires a human to verify the result). There is a tool for that too, called [`enca`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enca). This tool can also do the conversion once a guess has been made. It usually is a separate install (it is not part of the common default POSIX toolset). See [How to auto detect text file encoding?](https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding) over on Super User for more options.

Note however, given that codec guessing tools need to do so by using statistical analysis, it is better to do the guessing on the input file, not on the output of `grep`.

None of this has anything to do with Python, of course. Except if you wanted to do the encoding detection in Python instead, at which point you'd want to look at the [`chardet` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).